# Get stream from untyped message in streamed transfer mode

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to create streaming WCF service with contract

```
void Send(Message message)
```

I create message using

```
var requestMessage = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Default, "operation", new StreamableBodyWriter(inputStream));
```

where `StreamableBodyWriter` inherits from `System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamBodyWriter` and overrides `OnWriteBodyContents` to write input stream to message.

This seems to create `Message` correctly on client side but on service side I'm unable to read message content. When I inspect message body looks like this on both sides:

```
<s:Body>... stream ...</s:Body>
```

But `Message.IsEmpty` on service side is set to true.

Is there a way to get stream from Message body on service side?

Comment: From what I understood, are you trying to add something to the body and read it through the service?

Comment: Correct. I want to do streaming using untyped message. My service contract has to remain untyped because I don't have fixed service contract.

Comment: I am not sure but I think you can add headers to the SOAP but not modify the body, this will cause a "null" message. Did you tried Message inspectors?

Comment: I want to get same behavior as with Message Contract but problem is that Header parts are not fixed so my idea is to construct Message object myself. I donćt have problems with headers, or when I'm doing buffered transfer mode, only problem I've is how to pass stream from client to server and vice-verse. I will dig dipper into inspectors and see what can I get there.